# Regular Expression for Date format: D, dd M yy "Tue, 25 Oct 2011"

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for a regular expression to validation Date selected from a datepicker with format of D, dd M yy

```
 $('#expirydate').datepicker({
        constrainInput: true, 
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy'
    });
```

And the equivalent format in View is like this:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
    Expiry Date
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("ExpiryDate", String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { id = "expirydate" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
</div>
```

I could not get it in the regex library.. can anyone help??
Appreciate any feedback.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's coming from a datepicker, and you trust that it won't produce impossible dates, then to validate that format you could use:

```
(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun), [1-3]{1}[0-9]{0,1} (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{4}
```

Comment: hi, i wan to validate the date is because user can still input anything in the textbox and click submit...

Comment: I'd validate the format with regex, but then use some other method to validate that it's a real date. Maybe send it via ajax to a server-side function that uses DateTime.TryParse. Or you might can find a JS function that does it.. maybe [this](http://byatool.com/ui/jquery-validate-datecheck-if-is-date/)?

Comment: hi, i just realise that if i choose date like Tue, 01 Nov 2011 then I get the error from regex, and I realise that the regex got an extra "SUn", can you help me to validate the regex? really thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote a Regex for all the months, started to validate the days, and realized that you have to validate 28-31 depending on the month and year anyway.

Given that, you should skip the Regex and start looking down the road of looking at the [MSDN documentation on parsing data and time strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx)

If you really want to pre-check it with a regex, `(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun), (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([0-3]\d) (\d{4})` is the the basic setup.